# Cannot create or touch file inside LXC container

Tags: bash, lxc

Hi I have some problems with my LXC containers. If I run .sh script one, it does not create file in container, but the path exists. Sometimes, when I execute script several times, its working, i don`t know why.

Result:
    mkstemp: No such file or directory
    touch: cannot touch '/root/.ssh/config': No such file or directory
    /bin/sh: 13: cannot create /root/.ssh/config: Directory nonexistent

My script:

```sh
    # Lets define some variables.
    export CONTAINER="cv-app-backend-5"
    export SSH_SRC_PATH="./ssh"
    export SSH_DST_PATH="/root/"
    export SSH_CONFIG_PATH="/root/.ssh/config"
    export GIT_HOST="host"
    export GIT_URI="git@git.git"
    export APP_PATH="/root/app"
    export SSH_PATH="/root/ssh/id_rsa"
    export DB_USER="postgres"
    export DB_PASSWORD="postgres"

    #
    # Nothing below this point should need to be modified.
    #

    # Create a default Debian container.
    lxc launch 'images:debian/9' ${CONTAINER}

    lxc config device add ${CONTAINER} http proxy \
        listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:80 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:80
    lxc config device add ${CONTAINER} https proxy \
        listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:443 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:443
    lxc config device add ${CONTAINER} http proxy \
        listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:8080 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:8080

    lxc file push -r ${SSH_SRC_PATH} ${CONTAINER}${SSH_DST_PATH}

    # Run a script in the container
    cat <<EOF | lxc exec ${CONTAINER} -- /bin/sh

    echo "In container, phase 1"

    apt-get update
    apt-get -y install sudo git

    # Clone project repository
    pwd
    ls -la
    rm -rf ${APP_PATH}
    ssh-keygen -R ${GIT_HOST}
    touch ${SSH_CONFIG_PATH}
    echo "Host ${GIT_HOST}\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ${SSH_CONFIG_PATH}
    ssh-agent /bin/sh -c "ssh-add ${SSH_PATH}; git clone ${GIT_URI} ${APP_PATH}"
    cd ${APP_PATH}
    #In repository
    git checkout develop
    ssh-agent /bin/sh -c "ssh-add ${SSH_PATH}; git pull"
    #git reset --hard

    EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the failure is because when you create the debian/9 container, /root/.ssh does not exist.  So you can't copy files into it.  I don't see anything in the script you posted which would have the side effect of creating it.  But if something else just does an 'ssh-keygen', for instance, that would do it.

The simplest workaround would be to

```
lxc-exec -n ${CONTAINER} -- mkdir -p /root/.ssh
lxc-exec -n ${CONTAINER} -- chmod 700 /root/.ssh
```

before the lxc file push SSH_SRC_PATH.